# SSH Tunnelling error: "bind: Address already in use" after 1st successful use

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run Jupyter Notebook on a Virtual Machine.
I start the Jupyter Notebook by

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

I get the expected response, i.e. a link

```
http://127.0.0.1:8890/?token=***
```

Then I try forwarding by using

```
ssh -N -L 8889:localhost:8889 access_details@server_IP
```

After authentication, I get this message:

```
bind: Address already in use
```

That is all I get. There are no other additional messages. 
**This is what I have already tried** 
a. Kill processes using the port
b. Use different port 
c. Check other things that I had done, like killing screens, stopping everything, and starting from the start. 
d. Please note: It worked the first time I tried accessing it. It is not working from the second time I am trying to do it. 
e. Other keywords (might be helpful): Azure, Ubuntu.
f. Screenshot: 
[image]